# why focus move to above field while open to pop up in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am implementing the a screen in which i have one pop up screen .Actually when i fill the field in pop up screen focus goes to upper field .here is my fiddle.http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/uhdYv/
It is not display on my this fiddle .But if you copy this code in note pad and run on chrome than you find that focus goes to above field.

Take the following steps.
1)Copy code and save it on html include jquery mobile.
2)run on chrome.
3)Press + button pop up screen .fill first field 
then goes to date picker set date .then you see focus goes to above field.

please also insert css .In my fiddle .the issue is not display.

```
Here is my code..!!

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <title></title>

    <!-- Extra Codiqa features -->
    <!-- jQuery and jQuery Mobile -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.1.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js"></script>


      <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" /-->
    <link type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />       
    <!--script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script-->        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.core.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.calbox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.datebox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.flipbox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.durationbox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.slidebox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/i18n/jquery.mobile.datebox.i18n.en_US.utf8.js"></script> 





</head>


Please take code from fiddle..I don't know why it is going..?
```

Comment: Can you only provide the code causing the problem? currently there is too much of code.

Comment: actually focus is move upward ..Leave this question..!!

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699743/how-to-remove-the-current-date-from-date-box-in-jquery-mobile